# Pandas DataFrame, adding duplicate columns together

Tags: python, sum, duplicates

I have this really large DataFrame which has duplicate columns, but the values under it are not. I want to merge the duplicate columns together and add the values.

This really large DataFrame is made by appending Series together, and that is where the duplication occurs.

```
       Py Java Ruby C  Ruby
2010    1   5   8   1   5
2011    5   5   1   9   8
2012    1   5   8   2   8
2013    6   3   8   1   9
2014    4   8   9   9   9
```

So I want to add both Ruby columns together to get this result:

```
       Py Java Ruby C  Ruby
2010    1   5   13  1   5
2011    5   5   9   9   8
2012    1   5   16  2   8
2013    6   3   17  1   9
2014    4   8   18  9   9
```

I am running python 2.7

Answer (score 13):

I would propose to use groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

In order to make it work also for MultiIndex, one can do:

```
if df.columns.duplicated().any():
    all_levels = df.columns.nlevels
    if all_levels > 1:
        all_levels = range(all_levels)
    df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=all_levels).sum()
```

### EDIT

Instead of using groupby, one can now simply do:

```
df = df.sum(axis=1, level=0)
```

Be aware of nans, which will be converted to 0 by above procedures. To avoid that, one could use either `skipna=False` or `min_count=1` (depending on use case):

```
df = df.sum(axis=1, level=0, skipna=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to save the old column of values if you are summing them so here's a way to do it that way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':x, 'col2':y, 'col3':z}, index=a)
df.columns = ['Ruby', 'Python', 'Ruby']
df['Ruby'] = df['Ruby'].sum(axis=1)
df = df.T.drop_duplicates()
df = df.T
```

With a starting data frame that looks like:

```
        Ruby  Python  Ruby
2010     1       2     1
2011     2       4     3
2012     3       6     5
2013     4       8     7
2014     5      10     9
```

and then becomes:

```
        Ruby  Python
2010     2       2
2011     5       4
2012     8       6
2013    11       8
2014    14      10
```