# How to sum same countries in a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, log-analysis

I have a csv file and there are Count and Country columns. There are many Count and Country columns but this is the example I will write below.

```
Country     Count     Country     Count 
Japan        654       Japan       566   
 US           90        US          90
```

And I want the result :

```
Country     Total Count 
Japan          1220
US              180
```

How do I add the code in pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/giyan/Desktop/monthly report/geoip/finalsumgeoip.csv')
df['Total Count'] = df.filter(like='Count').sum(axis=1).astype(int)

df = df[['Country','Total Count']]
df.to_csv('podapoda.txt', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame, adding duplicate columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246014/pandas-dataframe-adding-duplicate-columns-together)

Comment: That's not a CSV file... There are no commas

Comment: you could read csv as pandas dataframe, that is what Aristu inherently meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the loc method for this. You can replace your your filter line with this:

```python
df['Total count'] = df.loc[df['A'] =df['C'],['B','D']].sum(axis=1)
```